# How do I display precisely the amount of requests made each n amount of time in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I’m working on a project where we want to metric the number of requests made every n amount of time filtered by some labels. Our data looks like:

`web_internal_request_count{filter1="1", filter2="2", endpoint="slots", instance="domain.here:port", integration="integration-name", job="web", method="GET", msg="OK", path="/path/to/integration", status="200"}`

We’re using a Counter in our middleware, so we increase the metric by filling the right labels and exposing these metrics to Prometheus so that it can scrape them. We’ve tried using the sum by(labels) () function, but the value at any given point is the current counter value, and we want to know how much it increased and when. We’ve tried using the increase function too, but it seems to estimate some values.

`increase(web_internal_request_count{integration=~"$integration", label1=~"$label1", label2=~"$label2", status=~"2..", endpoint=~"$endpoint"}[5m])`

[increase result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZMN7.png)

`sum(sum_over_time(web_internal_request_count{integration=~"$integration", label1=~"$label1", label2=~"$label2", status=~"2..", endpoint=~"$endpoint"}[$__rate_interval])) by (integration, label1, label2, status)`

[sum result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Ysx.png)

In conclusion, we want to display when the counter goes up and by how much. Have a nice day!

BTW: It's my first question posted here in StackOverflow, so any suggestion to improve or add more information to the text will be welcommed. Thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: `increase` is the function to get what you need. [It indeed uses some extrapolation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase), and there is no silver bullet to solve this. But you might search for something like `prometheus increase integer` and find a couple useful advises, including on SO.